# AngularJS: Is there a way to use ng-repeat to create rows and columns from the same array of data?

Tags: css, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am attempting to create a loop that will run through an array and output the data into rows/columns. For each two items in the array, i'd like it to create a new row with two columns, like this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">1</div>
   <div class="col">2</div>
</div>
```

Here is an example of my array:

```
$scope.array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
```

So, the overall end want would look like this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">1</div>
   <div class="col">2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">3</div>
   <div class="col">4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">5</div>
   <div class="col">6</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">7</div>
   <div class="col">8</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">9</div>
</div>
```

This is what I had originally attempted, but it was only showing up one column.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in array">
   <div ng-if="$index % 2 === 0" class="row">
      <div class="col">{{item}}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Any additional thoughts or direction on how I can achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: It might be better to use a two-dimensional array.

Comment: Could you provide sample output? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close!  Try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in array">
   <div ng-if="$index % 2 === 0" class="row">
      <div class="col">{{item}}</div>
      <div ng-if="$index + 1 < array.length" class="col">
         {{array[$index + 1]}}
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

All that you were missing was the second column.